# How to Update permalink of already made multiple post for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

is there a way to automatically refresh the permalinks in all of our post?

the content of our website are automatically updating and gathering data from another website. the only problem is that the permalink is not updating. we need to edit each post to get the right permalink.

is there a way to automatically bulk refresh the permalinks in all of our post?

Comment: Permalinks are called permalinks because they should be _permanent_ … So why would you want to “update” permalinks?

Comment: everyday we are synchronizing post from another website. because of this we noticed that the post title is different from the permalink.